# Remove Hover action when target is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, hover

I have a button and there are event listeners to display a tool tip text paragraph on hover and also one to remove the text display on mouseleave.  The button also has an Onclick event that opens an info window, collects user input and takes further actions.   The code snippet below shows the code for the hover and mouseleave which perform as expected.   Problem is that the hover text remains displayed when the button OnClick event is being processed.  So I used some of the same code within the OnCLick event to attempt to set the displayed tool tip to 'none'  but it does not work as it does in the mouseleave event and the tip remains visible while the button OnClick event processes.   When the button OnClick event completes,  the displayed popup hint disappears but I have determined this is because the cursor is no longer on the button so the MouseLeave event is being triggered.  How can I programmaticaly turn if off when I enter the OnCLick event processing?

```
const target = document.getElementById("tooltip-button");
const tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip-text"); 

target.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        tooltip.style.display = 'block';
      }, false);
target.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
       tooltip.style.display = 'none';
      }, false);

//lines used in the OnClick event
const tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip-text"); 
tooltip.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated!**

In this code, the click event listener hides the tooltip instantly and utilizes await with setTimeout to mimic a processing delay. Replace the simulated delay with your real processing code. After processing, display the tooltip as needed. This approach guarantees the tooltip is hidden before the onClick event processing, preventing it from being visible.

```js
const target = document.getElementById("tooltip-button");
const tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip-text");

target.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    tooltip.style.display = 'block';
}, false);

target.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    tooltip.style.display = 'none';
}, false);

target.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    // Hide the tooltip immediately
    tooltip.style.display = 'none';

    // Simulate a delay to showcase the asynchronous behavior
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

    // Your actual onClick event code here
    // Collect user input and take further actions
    console.log("Button clicked!");

    // After the onClick event is processed, you can show the tooltip again if needed
    tooltip.style.display = 'block';
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="tooltip-button">Click me</button>
<div id="tooltip-text">Tooltip text here</div>
```

Comment: Your suggestion behaved identically to what I had coded previously.  So using alerts to track what is happening here is the process.   The button  listener hover pops up the tool tip.   When the button is then clicked, the click listener does trigger and an alert placed after tooltip.style.display = 'none' indicates that the code is just prior to the functional code I added where the comment exists in your template.  At this point the tooltip is still visible and the display = 'none' has not resulted in any action.  Things fo  as I described in my original comment and the tip does go away.

Comment: Perhaps the screen does not update while there are active events/functions underway.

Comment: Hmm, this can be then addressed using setTimeout.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if that is still not answered.

Comment: PERFECTO!   The tool tip disappeared before the custom code was executed,; exactly the desired behavior.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Awsome, do you mind accepting the answer, it would be helpful for others.

Comment: If need help doing that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow#:~:text=Logged%20in%20as%20the%20person,previous%20acceptance%20and%20reassign%20it.